# Rearange rows in a pandas DataFrame based on MultiIndex values the pandas-way

Tags: python, pandas

I really want to know how this could be done in an elegant way with pandas. I have this DataFrame where the index is a `MultiIndex` with the two values representing a year and a catagory.

```
|               |   VAL |
|:--------------|------:|
| ('2018', 'A') |     0 |
| ('2018', 'B') |     1 |
| ('2018', 'C') |     2 |
| ('2019', 'A') |     0 |
| ('2019', 'B') |     1 |
| ('2019', 'C') |     2 |
| ('2020', 'A') |     0 |
| ('2020', 'B') |     1 |
| ('2020', 'C') |     2 |
```

I want it to look like this:

```
| CAT |  YEAR |  VAL |
|:----|-------|-----:|
| 'A' |  2018 |    0 |
|     |  2019 |    0 |
|     |  2020 |    0 |
| 'B' |  2018 |    1 |
|     |  2019 |    1 |
|     |  2020 |    1 |
| 'C' |  2018 |    2 |
|     |  2019 |    2 |
|     |  2020 |    2 |
```

- The first column is based on the second level of the MultiIndex.
- The second column is based on the first level of the MultiIndex.

I have no idea how pandas can help me here.

This is the MWE do produce the sample data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

# sub DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'CAT': list('ABC'),
        'VAL': range(3)
    }
)
df = df.set_index('CAT')
print(df)

# dict of 3 DataFrame's
d = {
    '2018': df.copy(),
    '2019': df.copy(),
    '2020': df.copy(),
}

# glue them together
df = pd.concat(d)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
# insert the YEAR column
df.insert(0, 'YEAR', df.index.get_level_values(0))

# insert the CAT column
df.insert(0, 'CAT', df.index.get_level_values(1))

# remove the index and sort values
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(['CAT','YEAR'])

# mask the duplicates with ''
df.loc[df['CAT'].duplicated(),'CAT'] = ''
```

Output:

```
  CAT  YEAR  VAL
0   A  2018    0
3      2019    0
6      2020    0
1   B  2018    1
4      2019    1
7      2020    1
2   C  2018    2
5      2019    2
8      2020    2
```

Answer (score 3):

```py
In [25]: df.swaplevel().sort_index(level=0)
Out[25]:
          VAL
CAT
A   2018    0
    2019    0
    2020    0
B   2018    1
    2019    1
    2020    1
C   2018    2
    2019    2
    2020    2
```

Use [`df.swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) then sort the index

If you want those actual columns (with empty strings where there's duplicates) instead of just swapping the MultiIndex, then see @Quang's answer

alternatively, building on the above

```py
>>> df2 = df.swaplevel().sort_index(level=0).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'Year'})
>>> df2['CAT'] = np.where(df2['CAT'].duplicated(), '', df2['CAT'])
>>> df2

  CAT  Year  VAL
0   A  2018    0
1      2019    0
2      2020    0
3   B  2018    1
4      2019    1
5      2020    1
6   C  2018    2
7      2019    2
8      2020    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
df.reset_index() \
.rename(columns={'level_0': 'YEAR'}) \
.sort_values(['CAT', 'YEAR'])[['CAT', 'YEAR', 'VAL']] \
.reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
  CAT  YEAR  VAL
0   A  2018    0
1   A  2019    0
2   A  2020    0
3   B  2018    1
4   B  2019    1
5   B  2020    1
6   C  2018    2
7   C  2019    2
8   C  2020    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Input:

|  | VAL |
| --- | --- |
| ('2018', 'A') | 0 |
| ('2018', 'B') | 1 |
| ('2018', 'C') | 2 |
| ('2019', 'A') | 0 |
| ('2019', 'B') | 1 |
| ('2019', 'C') | 2 |
| ('2020', 'A') | 0 |
| ('2020', 'B') | 1 |
| ('2020', 'C') | 2 |

```
df.insert(0, '{YEAR}', df.index.get_level_values(0))
df.insert(0, '{CAT}', df.index.get_level_values(1))
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(['{CAT}', '{YEAR}'])
df.loc[df['CAT'].duplicated(), 'CAT'] = ''
```

Output:

| CAT | YEAR | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 'A' | 2018 | 0 |
|  | 2019 | 0 |
|  | 2020 | 0 |
| 'B' | 2018 | 1 |
|  | 2019 | 1 |
|  | 2020 | 1 |
| 'C' | 2018 | 2 |
|  | 2019 | 2 |
|  | 2020 | 2 |